# Django Group objects by foreign Key field value

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = CICharField("Name", max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = CICharField("Name", max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = CICharField("Name", max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books", blank=True, null=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books", blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get all Books objects filter by publisher and group by Category. For eg.

```
books = Books.objects.all().filter(publisher=1).group_by('category')
```

Output be like,

```
[
{ category 1: [book1, book2, ...] },
{ category 2: [book3, book4,... ] },
 ]
```

Can anyone tell me, How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to do some aggregation on your data (such as count or sum). For this purpose you can use something like

```
from django.db.models import Count

books = Books.objects.all().filter(publisher=1).values('category').annotate(Count('id'))
```

Which will group your data by `category` and count your books ids based on each group. You can also read more about annotation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses).